# Integration of Heaviside (step) function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, step-function

Ok, I do not have much experiencing using (or even integrating) Heaviside-step functions, so I am looking for a little help. The integral in question is,
\begin{equation}
6m^2\int_0^\infty d\mu \frac{1}{\mu^3}\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{\mu^2}}\theta(\mu-2m)
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is the step-function. Any help direct help or hints is of course appreciated. (The reason it is actually in here in the first place is that without it the integral is divergent). I was thinking about performing integration by parts to turn the step-function into a delta-function $\delta(\mu-2m)$ but then the integral in the end would just give 0 when I know this integral is equal to $1/2$ (I am just trying to show that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\theta(\mu-2m)=
\begin{cases}
0\,\,\text{if}\,\,\mu<2m, \\
1\,\,\text{if}\,\,\mu>2m.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\infty d\mu \frac{1}{\mu^3}\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{\mu^2}}\theta(\mu-2m)=
\int_{2m}^\infty d\mu \frac{1}{\mu^3}\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{\mu^2}}.
$$

Comment: Oh.... Ok, that helps. Then the integration is just $\frac{1}{12m^2}\left(1-\frac{4m^2}{\mu^2}\right)^{3/2}$ which at the bounds becomes just $\frac{1}{12m^2}$ with the factor of $6m^2$ becomes simply $\frac{1}{2}$. Thank you!